# No me deja usar la librería caret en Rstudio: there is no package called ‘recipes’

Tags: rstudio

Me sale este error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> there is no package called ‘recipes’
> Además: Warning message:
> package ‘caret’ was built under R version 4.1.3

Ya me he instalado la versión más nueva hasta el momento de Rstudio, pero me sigue diciendo lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré esta información en la siguiente liga: https://community.rstudio.com/t/problems-in-installing-caret-package/126450

Y sugieren que primero intentes instalar primero el paquete *recipes*
con el comando

```
install.packages("recipes")
```